# IOS 10 - Swift 3.0: Stop the delegated function to save the image

Tags: swift3, delegates, xcode8, ios10, dispatch-async

I'm making an App with swift 3, xCode 8.2 and IOS10. The interface has a thermal vision screen (FLIR ONE). My question is, how can I take a photo? My code is:

```
import UIKit

class ThermalCameraVC: UIViewController,  FLIROneSDKImageReceiverDelegate, FLIROneSDKStreamManagerDelegate   {


    //MARK: OUTLETS
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelStatusCamera: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCargeCamera: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var icnCancelPicture: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var icnUploadPicture: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var iconTakePicture: UIButton!


    //MARK: VARIABLES
    var simulatorStatus = false
    var cameraBussy =  false


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        FLIROneSDKStreamManager.sharedInstance().addDelegate(self)
        FLIROneSDKStreamManager.sharedInstance().imageOptions =  FLIROneSDKImageOptions(rawValue:   FLIROneSDKImageOptions.blendedMSXRGBA8888Image.rawValue)!

        icnCancelPicture.isHidden = true
        icnUploadPicture.isHidden = true
    }

    //MARK: CANCEL PICTURE
    @IBAction func cancelPicture(_ sender: Any) {
        cameraBussy =  false
    }


    //MARK: UPLOAD PICTURE AMAZON S3
    @IBAction func uploadPicture(_ sender: Any) {


    }

    func flirOneSDKDelegateManager(_ delegateManager:   FLIROneSDKDelegateManager!, didReceiveBlendedMSXRGBA8888Image msxImage:   Data!, imageSize size: CGSize){
    let image = FLIROneSDKUIImage(format:   FLIROneSDKImageOptions.blendedMSXRGBA8888Image, andData: msxImage,  andSize: size)

        //HERE I NEED TO STOP THE DELEGATED FUNCTION TO SAVE THE IMAGE !!
        if self.cameraBussy{
            //cameraBussy = false

        }else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async{

                self.imageView.image = image
            }

        }
    }

    @IBAction func takeThermalPicture(_ sender: Any) {
        cameraBussy = true
        icnCancelPicture.isHidden = false
        icnUploadPicture.isHidden = false
        iconTakePicture.isHidden = true
    }

  }
```

How can I stop the flow of data in this delegated function? Because it is continually calling.

Comment: do you want to call delegate function flirOneSDKDelegateManager only once?

Comment: I want to stop delegate function when the usser press in button camera. Because in this moment will be the usser needs this frame for to send to API Rest.

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate value to nil.

```
 @IBAction func takeThermalPicture(_ sender: Any) {

        FLIROneSDKStreamManager.sharedInstance().addDelegate(nil)
        cameraBussy = true
        icnCancelPicture.isHidden = false
        icnUploadPicture.isHidden = false
        iconTakePicture.isHidden = true

    }
```